# Unable to scroll in android with appium using python

Tags: android, python, automation, appium, python-appium

I tried this piece of code:

```python
scrollObject = dict(direction="down", text="some_text", element=appium_driver_elem.id)
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject)
```

But I am getting an error saying:

> "appium_driver_elem does not have attribute like id" or sometimes nosuchelementexception.

What is the simplest way to scroll with `appium` in android using `python`? Any full test examples?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.driver.swipe(470, 1400, 470, x, 400)

self.driver.swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, duration)
```

`start_y` value represents bottom Y value & `end_y` value represents top Y value of the screen in your app.

Since to scroll we hold screen at bottom & move up.

value of x depends on how much you wish to scroll in one shot. 
Example: To scroll to the bottom, try 300. To scroll little x can be 1200

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't found an answer. So maybe you need to play a little bit rough.
You can use the `self.driver.scroll(self,SrcElem,DestElem)` function to swipe screen from bottom to top and check the element you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can also try to do

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
...
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.press(start_element).move_to(end_element).release().perform()
```

Actually, that's how scroll() function works. Once, I had an issue with self.driver.scroll(), so this can also be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Kandume-Luckcraft